# Where is my ~/.bashrc file in ROS?

Tags: ros, bashrc, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am wanting to work with a package called articulation_tutorials, I download but when I try to use Rosmake it appears that it a package is missing.

```
WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['articulation_tutorials'] [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Looking more in this page I saw that I need to add into my `~/.bashrc` the command

`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/articulation_tutorials:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}`

However I don't know where my `~/.bashrc` file appears (and actually I also need it in order to stop writing `source devel/setup.bash` every time -> If you guys could tell me how I should write this and if I need to do additional steps in order to stop doing it, I would be very thankful also). Could you guys please tell me where is it?

And by the way, I haven't created any additional workspace since I just need to run a .launch demo file like this:

`roslaunch webcam_demo-1cm-4x6-4x5.launch`

Thanks again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211008/where-is-my-%7E/.bashrc-file-in-ros?/) by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 cd ~/catkin_ws
vim ~/.bashrc;
```

You can replace `catkin_ws` with your workspace. If you didn't install `vim` use command `gedit` instead

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thank you. Now could you please tell me where should I put the "source devel/setup.bash" code? I saw in the end of the file this:

source "/home/diego/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"

I tried just source devel/setup.bash below this line and also to change this one, however I still need the source dev...

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-06-10**:
For me , I have two.
One is for set up ROS, `soucre /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`
Another one is set up for my workspace `catkin_ws`
it's like : `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `.bashrc` file is located at the user's home directory, it's a linux thing. There isn't a different `.bashrc` file for each ros workspace. But you have to source every one ros workspace you want to use. These "sources" are happening when you open a new terminal. So remember to open a new terminal after a `catkin_make`

Example (in my `.bashrc`):

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

source ~/navigation_ws/devel/setup.bash

source ~/pandora_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

P.S. When you have multiple workspaces the latter overlays the previous ones. For example my `navigation_ws` overloads some packages that exist in `/opt/ros/hydro`

---

Originally posted by [dimkirt](https://answers.ros.org/users/21067/dimkirt/) with karma: 63 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3